# How to access a file placed in a generic Folder inside of an ASP.NET Web Application

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio

I am trying to get the path of a file placed in a Folder Named ProductCatalog and the file is ProductsFile.xlsx. I want to give its path in a connection string for accessing and excel file. How can i do that? Following is the string in which i am trying to place the path of the data Source What should i write after the Comma ?:

```
constr = string.Format(@"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source={0};Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES""",   ));
```

Comment: After comma write what value pass in data source.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try with

```
string xlsNameWitPath = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/ProductCatalog/"), xlsFileName);
```

Comment: Thanks That Worked Perfectly!